# tcp fusion on Linux?

Tags: linux, solaris, tcp

Is there any equivalent of Solaris' TCP fusion (for loopback connections) on Linux ?
would it exist as part of a distro or a specific module ?
(the background for the question is the will to achieve the lowest latency loopback TCP communication between 2 processes running on the same system).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TCP fusion, but [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) sounds like a fit.

Comment: I know zeromq, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. just want to know if there's a technology such as TCP fusion that's transparently integrated in a linux kernel, or if that's a plan for a future distro / kernel.

Comment: Right, AFAIK the exiting IPC mechanisms are as good as it's going to get, but I'd probably post this question to somewhere like the kernel mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a filesystem based socket? AFAIK that's what TCP Fusion does albeit that TCP Fusion manes that you code as if it were a network socket.

Comment: filesystem based socket as in named pipe and such ? the problem is that I only control one side of the client-server pair, and the server does not offer this kind of connection option...

Comment: As in a Unix domain socket like socket(PF_UNIX...) (named pipes can mean something completely different). I'm out of ideas then